# Can 'even more' be used as a synonym for 'more importantly'?

Tags: synonyms

Can the phrase 'even more' stand for 'more importantly'? For example, 'If you drive while drunk, you could lose your license, but even **more importantly**, you could kill someone.' Is it correct to use 'even more' instead of 'more importantly' in this sentence?
'If you drive while drunk, you could lose your license, but **even more**, you could kill someone.'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, in my opinion this is not a natural phrase in English and the reader is left asking *'even more what?'*

A closer range of synonyms for 'more importantly' your example phrase might be:

> If you drive while drunk, you could lose your license, but **above all**, you could kill someone.
>
> If you drive while drunk, you could lose your license, but **what's more**, you could kill someone.
>
> If you drive while drunk, you could lose your license, but **moreover**, you could kill someone.